# Looping over a selected range trying to get cell values at a offset

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm that contains a range selection field and a button. There's also an XML template file that has "###" in a few places which will be replaced with our loop below.

Press the button and the form loops over the selected range and creates XML files, based on the XML template, for each cell in the selected(1 dimension) range with name being whatever is the current cell it's looping over in the range.

Find and replace is executed for each loop iteration to write to each file whatever the value of adjacent cells is(2 columns to the right) of the current loop item.

```
    ColA    ColB        ColC
    ABC     (empty)     123 // loop should create ABC.xml, DEF.xml, GHI.xml with 
    DEF     (empty)     456 // data inside 123, 456, 789 respectively in each .xml
    GHI     (empty)     789

// instead all three .xml will have 123 which is not what we want
```

Resulting files have proper names, **but all have the same data inside** - the value of the very first adjacent cell to the selected range. It's as if the loop loops over the range properly but references the very first adjacent cell during entire loop duration(stored in sAdjacentVal).

```
For Each i In selectedRange
        sFileName = i.Value & ".xml"
        sFullFileName = sPath & LCase(sFileName)

        'Grab adjacent value 2 rows to the right of the current loop item
        sAdjacentVal = i.Offset(0, 2).Value

        sTemplateXML = Replace(sTemplateXML, "###", sAdjacentVal)

        Set oFileStream = FSO.CreateTextFile(sFullFileName, True, True)
        oFileStream.Write sTemplateXML
        oFileStream.Close
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you perform the first replacement on the first loop with,

```
sTemplateXML = Replace(sTemplateXML, "###", sAdjacentVal)
```

Then the `sTemplateXML` no longer contains the `###` necessary to complete a replacement on the next loop.

```
dim tmp as string
For Each i In selectedRange
        sFileName = i.Value & ".xml"
        sFullFileName = sPath & LCase(sFileName)

        'Grab adjacent value 2 rows to the right of the current loop item
        sAdjacentVal = i.Offset(0, 2).Value

        tmp = Replace(sTemplateXML, "###", sAdjacentVal)

        Set oFileStream = FSO.CreateTextFile(sFullFileName, True, True)
        oFileStream.Write tmp   
        oFileStream.Close
Next i
```